# Attach variable depending on interval with DPLYR

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to merge a vector to a dataframe based on two conditions.

The first is that they are the same `item` and the second is that the entry occurred on the most recent reference date.

To give a mock example - take a dataset of sales

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("02/01/2018", "02/01/2020", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2020"), format = "%d/%m/%Y"), Item_Purchased = c("APPLE", "APPLE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE"))

> df1
            Date Item_Purchased
1     2018-01-02          APPLE
2     2020-01-02          APPLE
3     2019-01-02         ORANGE
4     2020-01-02         ORANGE
```

to which I want to attach the price on that date, using a dataframe of prices by date, like

```
df2 <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2020", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2020"), format = "%d/%m/%Y"), 
Item = c("APPLE", "APPLE", "APPLE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE"), 
Price = c(0.30, 0.35, 0.40, 0.60, 0.70, 0.75))

> df2
        Date   Item Price
1 2018-01-01  APPLE  0.30
2 2019-01-01  APPLE  0.35
3 2020-01-01  APPLE  0.40
4 2018-01-01 ORANGE  0.60
5 2019-01-01 ORANGE  0.70
6 2020-01-01 ORANGE  0.75
```

The cost of an apple on January 2nd 2018 is 30c, and its cost on January 2nd 2020 is 40c. Similarly the cost of an orange on January 2nd 2019 is 70c and January 2nd 2020 75c.

As such I need the merged dataset to look like:

```
  Date_Purchased Item_Purchased Price_On_Date_Purchased
1     2018-01-02          APPLE                    0.30
2     2020-01-02          APPLE                    0.40
3     2019-01-02         ORANGE                    0.70
4     2020-01-02         ORANGE                    0.75
```

If using base I could divide df1 based on Item_Purchased, subset the corresponding items from df2. Then using findInterval I could get the appropriate date in which the price was changed and get the corresponding Price value.

I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do it using dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("02/01/2018", "02/01/2020", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2020"), format = "%d/%m/%Y"), Item_Purchased = c("APPLE", "APPLE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE"))

df2 <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2020", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2020"), format = "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                  Item = c("APPLE", "APPLE", "APPLE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE"), 
                  Price = c(0.30, 0.35, 0.40, 0.60, 0.70, 0.75))

library(tidyverse)
left_join(df1, df2, by = c('Item_Purchased' = 'Item')) %>%
  filter(Date.x > Date.y) %>%
  group_by(Date.x, Item_Purchased) %>%
  slice_tail()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   Date.x, Item_Purchased [4]
#>   Date.x     Item_Purchased Date.y     Price
#>   <date>     <chr>          <date>     <dbl>
#> 1 2018-01-02 APPLE          2018-01-01  0.3 
#> 2 2019-01-02 ORANGE         2019-01-01  0.7 
#> 3 2020-01-02 APPLE          2020-01-01  0.4 
#> 4 2020-01-02 ORANGE         2020-01-01  0.75
```

which may finally be tuned to

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c('Item_Purchased' = 'Item')) %>%
  filter(Date.x > Date.y) %>%
  group_by(Date.x, Item_Purchased) %>%
  slice_tail() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Date_Purchased = Date.x, Item_Purchased, Price_on_date_purchased = Price)
```

---

OR

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c('Item_Purchased' = 'Item')) %>%
  filter(Date.x > Date.y) %>%
  group_by(Date.x, Item_Purchased) %>%
  summarise(Price_on_date_purchased = Price[Date.y == max(Date.y)],
            .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: That works great, however it seems due to the amount of data I have I hitting memory issues: ```Error: cannot allocate vector of size 222.6Mb``` Is there anything obvious I could do rather than split the data row wise and do each?

Comment: see alternate added